# Chinese characters being displayed as squares with WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: css, character-encoding, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I've been trying to display Chinese characters in the PDF document created by Rotativa (WKHTMLTOPDF), but unfortunately I've been only getting squares. However, the fonts are being properly displayed while in the regular HTML view.

I think I've tried every solution found on the internet but none of those were helpful.

1. Font family in css is set to `font-family: Tahoma,'Microsoft
   YaHei', sans-serif !important;`
2. Meta charset is set to `utf-8`
3. Font `Microsoft YaHei` is installed on the server.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I already worked on chinese projects. And even if I am not sure this is going to do the trick for your purpose, it did for me. Try this encoding:

> ISO-8859-1